# Does every matrix of the form $P J_p P^\top$ have exactly $p$ positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $J_{p}$ be the $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with $p$ ones followed by $n-p$ minus ones on its diagonal.  Let $P$ be an invertible $n \times n$ real matrix (not necessarily symmetric).

How many positive eigenvalues can $P J_p P^\top$ have?  Is it always equal to $p$?

I have not been able to find a counterexample (I generated a bunch of random matrices $P$) or a proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of $J_p$ as the matrix of a quadratic form, $PJ_pP^{T}$ is the matrix of the same quadratic form in a different basis (the base of the columns vectors of $P$). By the law of inertia, the number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues is preserved (see Sylvester's law of inertia). So your conjecture is correct.